# Apache Hadoop Common - FAILURE, while installing Hadoop

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.6.5 on Windows 7(32 bit). While running

mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar I am getting below error:

[image]

> JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
>
> PATH = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;E:\programs\Maven\apache-maven3.5.0\bin;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\usr\sbin;E:\programs\protobuf\protobuf-2.5.0 win;E:\programs\cmake\bin;E:\programs\hadoop\hadoop-2.6.5-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\bin

I couldn't find any solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the path can have spaces in it. Nor can there be any Cyrillic characters. If you look at the error message, File not found for `(D'D ,D'D`, which I doubt is your username

If you're not compiling custom code, you can just use the Hadoop binaries.

Comment: there is no space in path . 
But you are right in second point .. the user name is an arabic 2 words .. which it can be unidentified .. what is solution for it ??

Comment: As stated, download the Hadoop binaries instead of the source, extract to `C:\hadoop`, for example. You may want to do the same for Maven